# Centering image on Wordpress website

Tags: css, center

I'm trying to center the logo on this site: http://oliver.kaspertoxvig.dk/
Right now I've set

```
  #header hgroup {
  float: left;
  left: 50%;
  }
```

But as you can see it's not centered, it's more to the right side than the left one.
I can't figure out why it's not in center.

Answer (score 1):

Replace with this:

```
#header hgroup {
   position: relative;
   margin: 0 auto;
   display: block;
   max-width: 250px;
   float: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `left: 50%`centers the left side of an element in the parent `div`. If you want to center elements with a fixed width (as in your case), add half of the width as negative margin to the left, i.e. `margin-left -125px`. That does the trick.

Answer (score -1):

Why are you using relative positioning and float? You only need to set `text-align: center`.